# Is it mandatory to remove yourself as an observer from Android Lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I am building an Android Java class which implements the [`LifecycleObserver`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html) interface.

This is the constructor:

```
public MyObserver(AppCompatActivity activity) {
    this.mActivity = new WeakReference<AppCompatActivity>(activity);
    activity.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}
```

Is it necessary to ever call [`removeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html#removeObserver(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver)), using something like:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
public void destroyListener() {
    if (this.mActivity.get() != null) {
        this.mActivity.get().getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);
    }
}
```

Or, can I observe forever?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

TL;DR: Nope.

According to this [link here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-lifecycles/issues/5), where a user asked your question on the `android-lifecycles` Github repo. The answer of a Google developer to this questions was:

> Yes, that's the whole point of the new lifecycle-aware components, **no
>   need to unsubscribe/remove observers.**

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: You're better off explicitly removing the observer when you are done with it, or use something that handles this automatically, such as `LiveData`.

`Lifecycle` is an `abstract` class. So, technically, you have no idea what the implementation is and what the rules of the game are.

The one concrete `Lifecycle` is `LifecycleRegistry`. It has strong references to the observers. So now you are counting on the `LifecycleRegistry` being garbage-collected in a timely fashion, such as when the activity is destroyed. For `FragmentActivity`, that appears to be the case. So in practice, for the now-current version of all this stuff, you could get away without unregistering the observer and suffer few ill effects, if any.

But that's not part of the `Lifecycle` contract. Arguably, any decent implementation of `Lifecycle` (or things that use `LifecycleRegistry`) *should* cleanly handle the case where you fail to unregister... but I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: If you're registering observers for components that clearly have a different (shorter) lifecycle than the Activity, you should unregister appropriately. This is becoming a more common scenario than people realize, especially in the world of single activity apps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using LifecycleRegistry in a singleton object that manages audio sounds.
After adding LeakCanary it detected a memory leak because of this issue.

However, calling `removeObserver`, the memory leak never appeared again.

So it may be true that when using LiveData + LifecycleRegistry you don't need to unregister. But if it's a custom component using LifecycleRegistry, my experience shows that calling removeObserver is a must to avoid memory leaks.